# Drop down menu items based on another drop down menu

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to populate a drop down menu based on another drop down menu value

```
//Here's the first drop down menu
<select name="comp_type" class="form-control" >
   <option disabled selected value>Select</option>    
   <option value="Controller" >Controller</option>
   <option value="Processor">Processor</option>
   <option value="Module">Module</option>
   <option value="Board">Boards</option>
   <option value="Glue">Glue</option>
   <option value="Diod">Diod</option>
   <option value="Adapter">Adapter</option>
   <option value="Meter">Meter</option>
   <option value="Wire">Wires</option>
 </select>

 //Second drop down menu

 <select name="component_name">

    //Here component names should be displayed

 </select>
```

Every option in first drop down menu corresponds to different tables in a MySQL database.

If I select any option in first drop down menu, it needs to fetch the component names in the appropriate table and display the names in second drop down menu.

Comment: For this you have to use Ajax.

Comment: Improved formatting and general English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out calling AJAX and displaying data in a div: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.form-control').change(function(){
        var Value = $(this).val();
        if(Value != null){
            jQuery.ajax({     
                type: 'POST',         
                url: "getTableData.php?table="+Value,             
                success: function(data){ 
                    $('#resultDiv').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
</script>

<select name="comp_type" class="form-control" >
    <option disabled selected value>Select</option>             
    <option value="Controller" >Controller</option>
    <option value="Processor">Processor</option>
    <option value="Module">Module</option>
    <option value="Board">Boards</option>
    <option value="Glue">Glue</option>
    <option value="Diod">Diod</option>
    <option value="Adapter">Adapter</option>
    <option value="Meter">Meter</option>
    <option value="Wire">Wires</option>
 </select>

<div id="resultDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using 

$data=$_POST['comp_type'];

if($data === 'Controller'){  
$sql = "select * from comp_controller";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
If (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
            
            <option><?php echo $row['comp_name']; ?></option> 
            
        <?php
    }
}
}

in php file, but i didn't get any data @justbaron

Comment: Post an update to your question, rather than in the comments.